# Accessing a Virtual Environment from IDLE3 shell?

Tags: vnc, python-3, putty

On my pi3 I have created a virtual environment with Python3.

I run my pi headless, using my Windows 10 PC. I access the pi with 3 apps:
- PuTTY for terminal usage;
- WinSCP for a file Explorer; and 
- TightVNC Viewer as a GUI interface (IDLE3)

I often use the VNC (GUI) to debug python scripts, which I find easier than a terminal session (PuTTY).

I wrote a few scripts in the virtual environment, using PuTTY, and I would like to now access them using the GUI interface (VNC) but I don't know how to do it! Is there a command I can execute in the IDLE3 Python shell that allows me access to the virtual environment?

Comment: Which VNC Server is running on the Pi ? The preloaded RealVNC Server or something you got via apt-get ?

Comment: This  is a general programming question (which is off-topic), but essentially you must start the virtual environment and run IDLE from there.

Comment: @flakeshake I am using TightVNC Viewer as I indicated in my original question.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev I disagree with you... I didn't ask a question related to programming! My question is related to accessing a GUI interface within a virtual environment with a headless Rpi! Your suggestion was to 'start the virtual environment and then run IDLE from there'... I know that I can do that if my Rpi is connected to my monitor (HDMI) but I am trying to understand how I can do that when the Rpi is accessed through my network?

Comment: Please answer: Which VNC **server** runs on the Pi ?? This is extremely important. Also, "virtual environment" has a **very** special meaning for Python programmers and i am 100% sure you are mixing up technical terms, making this question unanswerable.

Comment: @flakeshake Sorry I misread your original comment and replied with which client I am running! I installed TightVNCServer (sudo apt-get install tightvncserver). Then I start the server as a systemd server which includes the command ExecStart-/usr/bin/vncserver. By virtual environment, I mean one which is set up for Python3 using the command 'python3 -m venv env_name --system-site-packages'. I am trying to use the environment as a testing sandbox. Are you still 100% sure I am mixing up technical terms?

Answer (score 1):

In a graphical environment, you must use a "terminal emulator" to access a terminal. I believe the program is just called "Terminal" in the "Start Menu" of the new (post-2016) desktop.

To start IDLE with(in) a virtual Python3 environment (venv) use following commands inside "Terminal":

```
cd ~/virtualenv_path/
source bin/activate
python3 -m idlelib.idle
```